# Is $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ with multiplication a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, matrices

I am looking at an exercise that saying $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ with multiplication, in other words the nxn matrices with real entries together with multiplication is a group. I wonder the following: do every element of this set have an inverse? I am not sure about it and i think it does not have to be this way. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: For reference: [General Linear Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The notation $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set/group of **invertible** $n \times n$ matrices with real entries.  So every element has an inverse by definition of the set.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As Alistair Savage said, $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with real entries, so checking each of the requirements:

1) The group operation is associative, as matrix multiplication is associative.

2) The identity is $I$, so an identity element exists and is part of the group.

3) Every element of the set has an inverse by definition.

4) Multiplication of matrices in $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ produces matrices in $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. Let $A, B \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. Then $AB$ is certainly a $n \times n$ matrix, and $AB$ is invertible, as $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$, and by definition of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$, $B^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$ exist and are elements of the group.